# how to use The gmail OpenInviter plugin in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, plugins, php

hi i am trying to use `openinviter` `gmail` plugin . i downloaded the `gmail.plg.php` from

http://debug.openinviter.com/download.php

i created a new project(not a codeigniter project) in `xampp->htdocs->gmail` when i tried to run the code it said .

```
Fatal error: Class 'openinviter_base' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail\gmail.plg.php on line 26
```

so i downloaded the `openinviter_base.php` and added to top of my `gmail.plg.php`  now the problem is nothing shown , how can i integrate this , any one know how to use this plugin .

and also i need to use this plugin with codeigniter , i have no idea .

i also saw this code , but unable to get an idea

http://code.google.com/p/spherenetwork/source/browse/trunk/plugins/lcOpenInviterPlugin/lib/openInviter/openinviter_base.php?r=146

please help me , i tried very much but failed , thanks ....................................

Comment: Please show us how u trying to integrate the class to your project. If you are trying to just include the class, CodeIgniter may face problem. Please try to use the class as a library and call $this->load->library('class_name'); This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The plug-ins are very coupled with the overall open inviter framework, so I just added basically the whole thing. Perhaps overkill, but nice if you want to add other plug-ins.  I placed the entire inviter tree at the top level (probably not the best place). I then added the following lib into the libraries directory.  This was taken off of one of the codeigniter forums.  Both in code grabbed from the forum and the main openinviter scripts, i found I had to put in a fair amount of small tweaks.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/* tky@tmo.blackberry.net inviter.php Fri May 22 04:00:19 GMT 2009 */

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/OpenInviter/openinviter.php');

class Importer
{
    var $ci;
    var $imported;
    var $open_inviter;
    var $plug_ins;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci=&get_instance();

        $this->open_inviter = new OpenInviter();
        $this->plug_ins = $this->open_inviter->getPlugIns();
    }

    public function grab_contacts($plugin,$username,$password)
    {
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/OpenInviter/openinviter.php');

        $this->open_inviter->startPlugin($plugin);

        if($this->open_inviter->login($username,$password))
        {
            $array = $this->open_inviter->getMyContacts();

            if(is_array($array) && count($array)>=1)
            {
                $this->imported        =    $array;

                //$this->_store_invited();

                return($this->imported);
            }
            else
            {
                return $array;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //return 'ERROR on login.';
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function login($plugin,$username,$password)
    {
        $result = FALSE;

        $this->open_inviter->startPlugin($plugin);
        if($this->open_inviter->login($username,$password))
        {
            $result = TRUE;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function _store_invited()
    {
        foreach($this->imported as $mail=>$name)
        {
            $a = array
            (
                //'user_id'        =>    ospc_user_id(),
                'name'            =>    $name,
                'email_address'    =>    $mail,
                'status'        =>    0,
                'time_imported'    =>    time()
            );

            $this->ci->db->insert('ospc_imported',$a);

            unset($a);
        }
    }
}
?>
```